# About NAS and SAN(protocols, architecture, etc..)

Tags: storage, nas, iscsi, san

I am currently kind of having trouble to understand between NAS and SAN.

As far as I figured out, NAS and SAN are kind of defined as below.

NAS(Network attached storage)
- Usually used as file storage and use Ethernet Infrastructure to communicate 
- As file storage, support protocols like NFS, CIFS, SMB, HTTP(S)

SAN(Storage Area Network) 
 - Network Protocol to communicate with block storage for data access. 
 - Configured with separated network system
 - Commonly based on Fibre Channel(FC) technology.
 - Could use iSCSI(in small and medium sized business) or FCoE for less expensive alternative to FC

So, below is my questions.
**1.** Is File Storage and Block Storage are the solutions? I researched and found that NAS is File Storage Solution and SAN Storage is Block Storage Solution. 
  - In that case, are their base infrastructure(storage device) same? Only different with protocols, network devices, may be storage os something that controls underline device and way of usage?

**2.** I found there are NAS Solutions that support iSCSI. But I found that iSCSI is SCSI Protocol that use TCP/IP Network system and SCSI is for block level storage communication protocols.
 - And Now I am confused. NAS is a file storage solution and how could that support iSCSI Protocol?

**3.** Are AWS root disk and EBS storage SAN Storage?
 - I read that SAN Storage configuration could be expensive so iSCSI or FCoE are less expensive way to configure.
 - With what technology AWS storage Infrastructure is configured??

I am kind of newly studying of these storage part computer science and got some questions.
Is there anyone can explain those questions clearly? 
Thank you.

Comment: There is a LOT of information out there on this topic.  For instance: https://www.backblaze.com/blog/whats-the-diff-nas-vs-san/

Comment: What research have you done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you call a "Solution". The basic infrastructure is the same it's a some kind of a "storage server" (storage system) with physical disk(s), but it very much dependent of technologies, vendors and various options. Typically, a storage system provides access to its physical disks with different protocols of 2 main groups: block-level protocols like SCSI or rarely ATA on one hand, or file-level protocols like NFS, CIFS, etc on the other. It doesn't mean, a storage system can't work in both, block and file modes.

Storage network - SAN can be build over FC, FCoE, converged infrastructure, pure TCP/IP for iSCSI, Infiniband or any other infrastructure. Typically, when people say "SAN" they mean Block storage devices and FC protocol, but it doesn't mean, that a file storage - NAS can't be connected with SAN and vice verse.